# How to use "\fontsize" from anyfontsize right?

Tags: fontsize

The baselineskip of onehalf should be passed and rescaled. If I use

```
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}
```

...

```
{\fontsize{0.05\textheight}{0.05\textheight}\selectfont 
Text over two lines will be passed so. 
Fill in some other useless words, for getting, that there is no baselineskipt.}
```

there is no baselineskip. Why does the "skip" parameter do not have any effect?

one possible Solution is:

```
{\fontsize{0.05\textheight}{0.05\textheight}\selectfont 
    \parbox{0.8\textwidth}{Text over two lines will be passed so. 
    Fill in some other useless words, for getting, that there is no baselineskipt.}}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are on the right track: You need to end the current paragraph so that your changes take effect.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{textpos}
\begin{document}
Text over two lines will be passed so. Fill in some other useless
words, for getting, that there is no baselineskipt.


{\fontsize{0.05\textheight}{0.05\textheight}\selectfont Text over
two lines will be passed so. Fill in some other useless words, for
getting, that there is no baselineskipt.\par}

\end{document}
```